# How can I use kable to display LaTeX in HTML while taking advantage of RStudio's LaTeX preview?

Tags: html, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I wanted to take advantage of Rmarkdown and RStudio's preview of $\LaTeX$ to produce `HTML` tables using `kable` and `kableExtra`.

- To use `kable` one has to create a data frame containing the contents to be displayed
- Writing the  $\LaTeX$ I wanted to display inside strings (like this: `"$\\LaTeX$"`) was confusing and did not allow me to preview the $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I found a convenient alternative was to create a separate `.Rmd` file in which each line contains a single cell of the table I want to produce, e.g., the file `"LaTeX.table.Rmd"`:

```
Row 1
$\text{Row 1}$
$\alpha^2$
Row 2
$\text{Row 1}$ 

Row 3

$\gamma^2$

$\text{Row 4}$
$\delta^2$
```

By editing and storing this information in a `.Rmd` file, I get the benefit of RStudio's $\LaTeX$ preview

I then wrote this function `read.latex.kable(filename, ncols, colnames)` which

- Reads a newline delimited file of table entries from `filename`
- Returns a dataframe that stores these entries by row in `ncol` columns, named according to `colnames`

```
read.latex.kable <- function(filename, ncol, colnames){
  as.data.frame(
    matrix(
      read.delim(file = filename, sep="\n", header=FALSE, blank.lines.skip = FALSE)[[1]],
      dimnames=list(NULL, colnames), ncol=ncol, byrow = T)
  )
}
```

Now these commands

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

kable(read.latex.kable("LaTeX.table.Rmd", 3, colnames=LETTERS[1:3]), escape=FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, protect_latex = TRUE, bootstrap_options = c("striped", "bordered"))
```

...produce this output:

[image: HTML table containing LaTeX formatted characters]